# How to get multiple inputs into spark sql statement?

Tags: sql, database, scala, apache-spark

I have tried passing 2 inputs into an sql statement but it is showing error like mismatched input.
dataset = Seq("Y", "02012021").toDF("fg","dob")

And the query is:
If FG = "Y" then this is a member record then this must be a valid date in the past in MMDDYYYY format and the Incoming value must be 8 bytes long.

If FG !='Y' then this is optional:
So, if  FG !='Y' and it is supplied, but invalid then NULL out. Null/Blanks ok.

```
spark.sql("""select *, case when FA_MBR_Selected_FG = "Y" and length(dob) = 8 and to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy') then dob else '' end as dob, case when
FA_MBR_Selected_FG = "Y" and length(dob) = 8 and to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy') then 'Y' else 'NULL' end as dob_flag from input""").show(false)
```

Please give the spark sql statement using case when statement for the above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `when` function.

Check below code.

Sample Data

```
scala> val df = Seq(
("Y","02012021"),
("Y","0201202"),
("N","02012021"),
("Y","02-01-2021"),
("Y","31022021"),
("Y","01022020")
).toDF("fg","dob")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [fg: string, dob: string]
```

```
scala> 
df
.withColumn(
     "new_dob",
      when(
           $"fg" === "Y" &&  // to check fg column has "Y"
           length($"dob") === 8 &&  // to check dob length 8 characters or not.
           to_date($"dob","MMddyyyy").isNotNull, // Checking dob is in required date format or not.
           $"dob" // if above conditions are matched it will return dob value else it will return null.
      )
)
.show(false)

+---+----------+--------+
|fg |dob       |new_dob |
+---+----------+--------+
|Y  |02012021  |02012021|
|Y  |0201202   |null    |
|N  |02012021  |null    |
|Y  |02-01-2021|null    |
|Y  |31022021  |null    |
|Y  |01022020  |01022020|
+---+----------+--------+
```

Spark SQL

```
spark
    .sql(
      """
        |SELECT
        |   *,
        |   (
        |    case
        |       when fg = 'Y'
        |            and length(dob) = 8
        |            and to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy') is not null
        |       then
        |            dob
        |       else null
        |       end
        |   ) as new_dob
        |FROM hivetbl
        |""".stripMargin
    ).show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+---+----------+--------+
|fg |dob       |new_dob |
+---+----------+--------+
|Y  |02012021  |02012021|
|Y  |0201202   |null    |
|N  |02012021  |null    |
|Y  |02-01-2021|null    |
|Y  |31022021  |null    |
|Y  |01022020  |01022020|
+---+----------+--------+
```

Change `to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy')` to `to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy') is not null`

Try Below Query

```
spark.sql("""select *, case when FA_MBR_Selected_FG = "Y" and length(dob) = 8 and to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy') is not null then dob else '' end as dob, case when
FA_MBR_Selected_FG = "Y" and length(dob) = 8 and to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy') then 'Y' else 'NULL' end as dob_flag from input""").show(false)
```

Comment: can you please edit the same on this sql statement using flag --------------spark.sql("select case when FA_MBR_Selected_FG in MMDDYYYY then substring(FA_MBR_Selected_FG,1,8) else '' end as FA_MBR_Selected_FG, case when FA_MBR_Selected_FG in

MMDDYYYY then 'Y' else 'Invalid date format' end FA_MBR_Selected_FG_flag from input").show('invalid')

Comment: there is a datatype mismatch on the following query can you please correct it-----------input   :   val sample = Seq(("N","02011999")).toDF("FA_MBR_Selected_FG","dob")             -query:   spark.sql("""select *, case when FA_MBR_Selected_FG = "Y" and length(dob) = 8 and to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy') is not null then dob else '' end as dob, case when
FA_MBR_Selected_FG = "Y" and length(dob) = 8 and to_date(dob,'MMddyyyy') then 'Y' else 'NULL' end as dob_flag from input""").show(false)

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(((input.`FA_MBR_Selected_FG` = 'Y') AND (length(input.`dob`) = 8)) AND to_date(input.`dob`, 'MMddyyyy'))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(((input.`FA_MBR_Selected_FG` = 'Y') AND (length(input.`dob`) = 8)) AND to_date(input.`dob`, 'MMddyyyy'))' (boolean and date).; line 1 pos 17;

Comment: spark.sql("select case when cast(age as int) is not null then age else '' end as age, case when cast(age as int) is not null then 'Y' else 'age must be a number' end as age_flag from input").show(false)----------------------------------------------------------------------can you please add the condition of "if age is not provided , we dont need any validation" in the above sql statement